# Fatal error due to the "$this" object. (I'm new at this PHP stuff so I need some clarification please.)

Tags: this

There's an addon that I used on my Sharetronix website (a microblogging platform for those who aren't familiar with it) which is supposed to allow me to add a page to the root folder of my website.  But, I get this message when I go to the page that I just added.

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/u556426868/public_html/forum.php on line 2

I've done some research online and I know so much as the "$this" object shouldn't land outside of the "newtemplate_code()" but I don't know what I'm supposed to do in terms of replacing and fixing the code so that the page works.

The code for the whole page is as the following:

```
<?php   
    $this->load_template('header.php'); 
?>  
        <div id="pagebody" style="margin:0px; border-top:1px solid #fff;">
            <div><div id="contacts_left" style="width:100%;">           <div class="ttl">
                        <div class="ttl2"><h3>iState RPG - The Neovita RPG Forum</h3></div></div>
<br><br>


<center><iframe name=”FRAMENAME” src=”http://istate.serverforumhosting.com/portal.php” width=”1000? height=”1100? frameborder=”1? scrolling=”yes” allowautotransparency=true></iframe></center>

<! REMOVE FROM HERE THE DUMMY CONTENT !>

<b>DOWNLOAD</b> this plugin <a href="http://sharetronix.com/sharetronix/demo/view/post:3965797" title="Download from Sharetronix" target="_blank"> here</a>(2kb).<br><br>

<center>
<a href="http://sharetronix.com/sharetronix/demo/getfile/pid:public_3965797/New%20Page.rar" target="_blank" title="Download">
<img src="http://wb-cc.de/oscommerce/images/download-1.gif" border="0">
</a><br><br>

Brought to you by <a href="http://istate.tk">iState - The state of you!</a>
</center>

<! REMOVE END !>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php

    $this->load_template('footer.php');

?>
```

Like I said, I'm new to PHP coding and so I will need some clarification.  So by the way, thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using $this outside a class. I suggest you are trying to use a 3rd party library for templates. First of all you have to include the needed files link this:

```
include("path/to/your/class.php");
```

Then you have to find out the name of the class, let's say it starts like this:

```
class Template
```

Then you will have to initialise it with

```
$template = new Template();
```

and call the needed function

```
$template->load_template('header.php');
```

More details about path and usage may be in the installation files of the library.

Oh and `$this` is only for usage inside classes, e. g.:

```
class foo
{
    function bar()
    {
        // Do something
    }

    function do_bar()
    {
        $this->bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I have this = Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE in /home/u556426868/public_html/forum.php on line 4 which I don't really know how to solve either.  :/

Comment: Asking my local oracle because you provide no source code ... it's global warming! :-D

Comment: lol sorry... I don't know how i could insert the code while making it make sense since the code function makes it look like this: `class Template
{
    function bar('header.php')
    {
        // Do something
    }

    function do_bar('header.php')
    {
        $this->load_template('header.php');
    }
}`  I just replaced the $this->load_template... with all of that.  :p

Comment: No, you missunderstood. I just wanted to show, how it's correct to use `$this`. You can always edit your opening post. Maybe you should tell us, what you have and what your are hoping to do. A good start with OOP will be http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php but in my opionion start with simple functions.

Comment: Ah.... Alright, of course that would happen with me.  But thanks for all of your help and for the link, I'm pretty sure that would help me a lot as well.  ^_^